# Pylons config has a different content in websetup.py

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

In my pylons application I want to add some data on setup. ( a user)

To secure passwords in the database i've hashed the passwords with a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29), this salt is stored in the configuration file.

If I want to get the saltkey from configuration I do this (shortened example):

```
from pylons import config

saltkey = config.get("saltkey")
```

If this code is placed in for example a model, it returns the saltkey. In the User-model this code is used to create a hash with the salt.

However if I want to create an instance of this model in "websetup.py" the config has a different contents and it cannot retrieve the saltkey (resulting in an error)

```
def setup_app(command, conf, vars):
   load_environment(conf.global_conf, conf.local_conf)

   Base.metadata.create_all(bind=Session.bind)

   user = User('admin', 'password123', 'test@test.com')
   Session.add(user)
   Session.commit()
```

My question is: Why has the config a different content? And how do I fix this problem without an ugly hack?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your config file in this step.  The `from pylons import config` method is best suited to doing so in the context of a WSGI request.  However, you're not dealing with a WSGI request, so it's unavailable.  Fortunately, you have a very easy way of accessing config during `websetup.py`'s operation.  The `setup_app()` function already consumes the config file, and Paster has already parsed it and turned it into a dictionary for you.

You can access your config file as the `conf.local_conf` dictionary, and that will make the data you want available.

With all of that said - you should not store the salt in your config.ini file, [that's a bad idea and you should avoid wheel-reinvention like that](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html).